# Popup alert on visibilitychange make page stuck

Tags: javascript, dom

I've got a problem with the following method:

```
var blocked = false;

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
 if (!blocked && document.hidden) {
   blocked = true;
   alert('Blocked once');
 }
});
```

I want to show alert to the user once if he tries to switch tabs.
this works fine, but after the alert pop-ups it's making the page stuck.

I've illustrated it with the following plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/4NluXEQlal33yq06jwt6?p=preview

- Try to change the text in the input after seeing the alert. it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

> The visibilitychange event is fired when the content of a tab has
>   become visible or has been hidden

In your case it has been hidden (locked screen). You can't change `document.visibilityState`, it's read only value.

Check out the JavaScript [onbeforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), maybe it will be helpful.